# How to write config files for python scripts

Tags: python, json, config

I working improve the quality of the scripts I write to make them more maintainable avoiding hard coding values. So far I'm using a json file to save this values, E.G.

A json file called config_test.json:

```
{"input_dir":"data/input",
"output_dir":"data/output",
"default_value":10,
"dtypes":["str","int","str","float"]
}
```

Then I read this values from the main file:

```
import json
with open('config_test.json') as f:
    config_d = json.load(f)
config_d

default_value =   config_d['default_value']
dtypes =   config_d['dtypes']
input_dir =   config_d['input_dir']
output_dir =   config_d['output_dir']
```

I'm not completely comfortable with this solution, is there any standard approach to writing config files in python?

Answer (score 1):

**Make your life easier with pyyaml**

```
import yaml

with open("settings.yml", 'r') as stream:
    data = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

Your settings.yml =>

```
ip_address : '0.0.0.0'
sqlite     : 'sqlite:///data.db'
key        : 'super-secret-hoho'

answers:
    technology: ['option3', 'option3', 'option4', 'option3', 'option3', 'option4', 'option4', 'option2', 'option3', 'option3']
```

Then access with

```
my_not_hardcoded_ip = data['ip_address']
```

Its better to read and cleaner , i totally recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

Do not discount the possibility of writing your config file in Python itself.

**some_dir/app_config.py**

```
input_dir = "data/input"
output_dir = "data/output"
default_value = 10
dtypes = "str int str float".split()
```

**bin/app.py**

```
import argparse
import app_config as config

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--inputdir', default=config.input_dir)
```